# What is the best data structure to store, search and delete the element out of array, linked list, stack and queue?

Tags: arrays, data-structures, linked-list, stack, queue

I have a program where I will add the user name and delete the user name on certain conditions such as user return the book to library which means I will have to search the name in the data and the user data will be deleted now from some array or list or whatever data structure is best to use it.

I have four data structure. Array, Linked list, Stack and Queue? I was wondering which one is consider best for adding, searching and deleting the elements?

Comment: Why don't you tell us what you think is the best? First, consider whether it's even possible to search `Stack` or `Queue` efficiently, or even insert and delete at arbitrary positions. Have you done any analysis at all to inform your decision?

Answer (score 0):

From the four mentioned data structures none supports efficient search, and only Linked list support efficient deletion. If the user name is string (and I suppose it is) the trie data structure would be the optimal one. It supports `Θ(k)` addition, search, and deletion where `k` is the length of a string.